# Automatic formatting of LaTeX table

Tags: tables, formatting

I have a table `table.tex` coming from a statistical software `Stata`.

I would like to know if there is a way to tell LaTeX to format, for instance, some coefficients in red and italic. Something that would automatically search and replace strings in the `table.tex` file?

My setup is: WinEdt 6 on Windows 7.

Comment: Does Stata produce TeX output? If it works like R there may be output routines that use standard LaTeX packages and you can define the formatting from within Stata before the table is output. For example: [Tabstat in LaTeX](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/STAT/stata/latex/tabstat_stata.htm). See also: [Automated table generation in Stata and integration into LaTeX](http://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout/).

Comment: YES this is exactly what I use in my latex file. Unfortunately there is no trick in Stata (at least i am not aware of any) to change the format of a result...

Comment: Which do you use, latabstat?  Is there no way to modify its output?

Comment: What about using WinEdt "search and replace" feature?

Comment: i would like to automate the search... for instance automatically scanning for certain values in the table and highlighting them in red

Comment: @noobie_on_android The second link I gave seems to give more flexibility.  Also, if you use the `array` package, you can easily create custom columns so that if e.g. a certain column is supposed to be red you can do things like `\newcolumntype{R}{>\color{red}{r}}` which makes a right aligned red column. For individual values this won't work, obviously. Clearly Stata lags behind R in this respect.

Comment: @noobie_on_android If you are not able to solve your problem from Stata side let me know if you want any help to solve it from WinEdt side. There is also a package to run Stata syntax from within WinEdt: see [here](http://www.winedt.org/Config/modes/Stata.php)

Comment: hello karl yes from the stata side i know that there is no hope. maybe winedt can help?

Comment: @noobie_on_android Try to explain what is your problem and see the edit on my previous comment. PS: add my name preceeded by `@` to notify me...

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions. I found a solution in stata actually ;-)

Comment: @noobie_on_android Although we don't get a lot of Stata users here, it might be helpful to others if you could at least summarize your solution or show what you did as an answer.  We have similar questions for R that have been helpful to many.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a helper application which would need to be modified to solve the problem.